# Handle Commander errors manually in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, error-handling, command-line-interface

I'm writing a simple Commander CLI as part of a project I'm working on.

Commander has its own method of handling errors. For example, if the user enters an invalid command, then Commander will print a user-friendly message:

```
$ my-commander-program some-invalid-command
invalid command. Use --help for more information.
```

I would like to replace this message with my own, so that the output is more consistent with the rest of my program. For example:

```
$ my-commander-program some-invalid-command
[ERR ] 'some-invalid-command' is not a known command.
       Use --help to see a list of valid commands.
```

I've looked at Commander's README.md, which contains plenty of examples of how to use Commander, but I can't find how to do this from there.

My program is written using Commander's 'classic' style, where one imports `commander/import` and uses methods like `program` and `command` from the top-level, rather than creating a class which includes `Commander::Methods`. For example:

```
require 'commander/import'

program :name, 'my-commander-program'
program :version, '1.0.0'
program :description, 'Example'

command :example do |c|
  c.action do |args, options|
    puts "Invoked!"
  end
end
```

How can I go about replacing this error message? I'm using Commander 4.4.5.

Comment: Commander does not support formatting the error message output. You could file a ticket for a feature request. Monkey-patching the code yourself is another option.

Comment: @Casper That's a shame - thanks.